# Почему при условии "false", трассировка входит в блок "true"

Tags: delphi

Как-то не понятно отрабатывает трассировка кода:

```
begin
  if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) < 10 then
  begin
    showmessage('Hi');
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

при:
"*Edit1.Text = 20*" и соответственно условие выдает **false**, компилятор тормозится на *breakpoint* строки "exit", но пропускает вывод сообщения.
Когда по идее, в этот блок он вообще **не должен** попадать.

Comment: это дебагер врет - так как Ваш exit не нужен, небось еще и оптимзация включена

Comment: Так это он у всех так отрабатывает?  Ух... а я уж... Ага, включена...

Comment: спокойствие, только спокойствие. Дебагер - это дело житейское.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это оптимизация компилятора. Просто `Exit;` избыточен внутри блока `begin..end` в данном контексте. Добавьте строчку кода после первого `end;` и увидите, что все работает как надо.

```
begin
  if StrToInt(Edit1.Text) < 10 then
  begin
    showmessage('Hi');
    exit;
  end;
  showmessage('Bye');
end;
```

Comment: да, в принцыпе можно и только перед *end* добавить, тоже будет видно работать "как надо" :)